# Is there any function which call when subscribe success function is completed

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, rxjs, observable

In the below code i want to navigate when all the subscribe function will completed successfully but in my case it is navigating when customer is created and it is not waiting for the address creating successfully.Any Help will Highly Appreciated

```
createCustomer(model: any) {
        let isSuccess:boolean=true;
        this.loading = true;
        this.errorMsg = "";
        this.createCustomerService.createCustomer(model).subscribe(res => {
          this.tempCustomer = res;
          console.log("Returned Response is");
          console.log(this.tempCustomer);
          if (model.addressType.home.street_address) {
            this.createCustomerService.addAddress(this.tempCustomer.id, "HOME", model.addressType.home, model.cc).subscribe(res => {
            },
              err => {      
                this.errorMsg = err;
                this.alertService.error(err);
                this.loading = false;
              });
          }
          if (model.addressType.work.street_address) {
            this.createCustomerService.addAddress(this.tempCustomer.id, "WORK", model.addressType.work, model.cc).subscribe(res => {
            },
              err => {
                this.errorMsg = err;
                this.alertService.error(err);
                this.loading = false;
              });
          }
          if (model.addressType.other.street_address) {
            this.createCustomerService.addAddress(this.tempCustomer.id, "OTHER", model.addressType.other, model.cc).subscribe(res => {
            },
              err => {
                this.errorMsg = err;
                this.alertService.error(err);
                this.loading = false;
              });
          }

        },
          err => {
            this.errorMsg = err;
            this.alertService.error(err);
            this.loading = false;
          },
          ()=>this.router.navigate(['/pages/searchcustomer']));

        // if (!this.errorMsg) {
        //   this.router.navigate(['/pages/searchcustomer']);
        // }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use forkJoin

**forkJoin subscribe will be called after completion of all Observable**

```
ob1 = this.createCustomerService.addAddress(this.tempCustomer.id, "HOME", model.addressType.home, model.cc);
ob2 =  this.createCustomerService.addAddress(this.tempCustomer.id, "WORK", model.addressType.work, model.cc)
ob3 = this.createCustomerService.addAddress(this.tempCustomer.id, "OTHER", model.addressType.other, model.cc)

    Observable.forkJoin([ob1, ob2,ob3]).subscribe(results => {
      // results[0] is our ob1
      // results[1] is our ob2
      // results[2] is our ob3
    });
```

Note I am assuming that these are Observable one time call otherwise you can use **Zip**

Comment: These all address are not mandatory. we have to fill one address at least. Now the problem in forkjoin is that we have to write so many if else statement for doing fork join.

Comment: If you have optional address than you need improve your design. your backed should handle that operation. Front End will send array of address and backed will save array of address.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice i have change my flow .

Comment: if you don't have other question you can accept as Answer.

Comment: i have one more problem.
There are some problems when you use getrawvalue(). it will only give the updated value of your form. suppose we use a submit button to call a function and update some model data.after that we get a new button in the view which will finally submit the form values. so in this case you will only get the value which you type in the form and you will not get the updated value which you have done on first button submission.